# Lua: Passing index of nested tables as function arguments?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is it possible to have a function that can access arbitrarily nested entries of a table?
The following example is just for one table. But in my real application I need the function to check several different tables for the given (nested) index.

```
local table1 = {
  value1 = "test1",
  subtable1 = {
    subvalue1 = "subvalue1",
  },
}

local function myAccess(index)
  return table1[index]
end

-- This is fine:
print (myAccess("value1"))

-- But how do I access subtable1.subvalue1?
print (myAccess("subtable1.subvalue1???"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this using a string unless you use `load` to treat it as Lua code or make a function to walk on a table.

You can make a function which will split your string by `.` to get each key and then go one by one.

You can do this using gmatch + one local above gmatch with current table.

Comment: The argument does not need to be a string, if there is another way? How does "going one by one" work?

Comment: @Linus well if you can do it in script just do `table1.subtable1.subvalue1`, if it never changes. one by one is done by gmatch because it will be called for each key.
`for key in string.gmatch(index, "[^.]+") do print(key) end`

Comment: My function should check if table1.subtable1.subvalue1 exists, and if not it should return table2.subtable1.subvalue1.  So I have to tell my function it should check for subtable1.subvalue1.

Comment: make a local before gmatch to table1, use gmatch keys and go to next table. check if it's nil.

Comment: I posted another answer. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: @Linus Yes, you get it, you mark my answer as "Accepted"

Answer (score 1):

@Spar: Is this what you were suggesting? It works anyway, so thanks!

```
local table1 = {
  value1 = "test1",
  subtable1 = {
    subvalue1 = "subvalue1",
  },
}


local function myAccess(index)
  
  local returnValue = table1
  for key in string.gmatch(index, "[^.]+") do 
    if returnValue[key] then
      returnValue = returnValue[key]
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
  
  return returnValue
end

-- This is fine:
print (myAccess("value1"))

-- So is this:
print (myAccess("subtable1.subvalue1"))
```